# Django csv file import to database

Tags: django

I want to import csv file into database form local PC,

```
DB:mysql
OS CentOS Apache
```

I have below error

```
module' object has no attribute `__getitem__`

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filename = request.FILES["file1"]
        content = request.FILES["file1"]
        path = os.path.join("/tmp", csv)
        file = open(path, "r+b")
        file.reader(content)
        reader = csv.reader( file)
        for row in reader:
            tmp = User.objects.create()
            tmp.UserID = row[0]
            tmp.user_name = row[1]
            tmp.first_kana = row[2]
            tmp.last_kana = row[3]
            tmp.save()
        file.close()
        return HttpResponse("/memo/all")
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['upload'] = User.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('importcsv.html', args)

below is importcsv.html:
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <form action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="file" name="file1">
        <input type="submit" value="import">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What's the full error stack? It looks like it got cut off.

Comment: I have this error <module' object has no attribute `__getitem__`>

Comment: That's all you get back?  Add ```--traceback``` to your manage.py scrip to get more info. I don't see anything in the code you posted that would cause that.  Could you update it with the full file?

Comment: I have moved successfully now, modification to
 Path and filename, thank you!!

Comment: Yes, above is my full file!